# Function to add mix with alpha

Tags: glsl, lwjgl

```
#version 140

in vec2 textureCoords;

out vec4 out_Color;

float alpha = 0.5;

uniform sampler2D guiTexture;

void main(void){

    out_Color = texture(guiTexture,textureCoords);

}
```

I am pretty (very) new to GLSL.

I want to basically add a transparency value (float) to the following code above (don't bother running it I just had to get it in). The value float should be the float a (4th component) in the out_Color variable. However due to the code currently in there which is 4 components I am not sure how to. Is there a function that will allow me to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You should take](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-tutorial/data-types/) [a look at](http://nehe.gamedev.net/article/glsl_an_introduction/25007/) [pretty much](https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki/Shaders) [any basic](http://wiki.lwjgl.org/wiki/GLSL_Tutorial:_Syntax) [GLSL tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/70208/opengl-es-pixel-shaders-tutorial)

```
out_Color = vec4(texture(guiTexture,textureCoords).rgb, alpha);
```